# Join Postgres Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Im fairly new to Rails and Postgres. What I want to achieve is a list of users that are my friend and have rated the game.

This is what I got.

This will retrieve all my friends

```
-@friends = current_user.friendships.includes(:friend)
```

This will retrieve all the ratings.

```
-@ratings = @game.rates.order(created_at: :desc).includes(:user)
```

This code currently works, but obviously I want to do this in 1 call instead of cycling trough each.

```
-@friends = current_user.friendships.includes(:friend)

-@ratings = @game.rates.order(created_at: :desc).includes(:user)

-@ratings.each do |rate|
  -@friends.each do |f|
    -if f.friend_id == rate.user.id

      div= link_to rate.user.username, rate.user
```

So how do I achieve this?

Comment: friend is a user? What are the relations between these tables?

Comment: Friend_id is an ID of a user, aswell as rate.user.id